# How to hide/disable unused wifi adapters

Tags: networking, 20.04

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 and I'm using a wired connection so have no need of the wifi connections shown in the below screenshot.

The USB wifi option is a usb xbox one controller adapter I use on windows and the PCI wifi is built into my motherboard.

**Is it possible to disable these two devices from showing up as connection options in this drop down menu?** I don't necessarily want to stop them from ever functioning in the future. I'd still like to be able to re-enable if I wanted to, but as I regularly use VPN's the extra options I never need in the screenshot just get in the way.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Output of `ip addr show` - I'm not really sure what most of these are, so I don't know for sure which relate to the wifi adapters in question.

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

2: eno2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 30:9c:23:ec:61:93 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.50.123/24 brd 192.168.50.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eno2
       valid_lft 65241sec preferred_lft 65241sec
    inet6 fe80::7a58:e1e8:c1bf:a7bc/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

3: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 04:d3:b0:cb:f8:54 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

5: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:32:62:1b:5f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

6: br-70eef461a985: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:94:2b:e0:a2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.19.0.1/16 brd 172.19.255.255 scope global br-70eef461a985
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

7: br-725d1f08dc0b: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:ce:f9:65:22 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.21.0.1/16 brd 172.21.255.255 scope global br-725d1f08dc0b
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

8: br-c1fb8431138c: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:6f:5d:30:ac brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.18.0.1/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global br-c1fb8431138c
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

12: wlx6245b501db3f: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 62:45:b5:01:db:3f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: @UnKNOWn Oh very nice - that worked a treat! VPN remains and only wifi is hidden, feel free to write this down as an answer. Thanks very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to hide the wifi box from the network menu.

Run the below command to hide it

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval "Main.panel.statusArea.aggregateMenu._network._devices.wireless.box.hide()"
```

to revert back above command replace `hide` with `show`

Please note that when ever gnome-shell refreshes, the above command will reset to original state.. The workaround for this is to create a gnome-shell-extension.

for logout and reboots the persistence can be achieved by adding the above command in startup applications list.

Comment: Perfect - thanks for the additional info on persisting this on startup